# How to make loop faster while changing image src in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, axios

Actually I am retrieving some large data from my MySQL using PHP, Axios and I used get method which is absolutely fine... the data is some img src now I use the loop to change the image src but it is taking too much time to change the src almost 5 to 10 sec

```
function show(){
        axios.get('php/retrieve_characters.php')
        .then(function(response){
             var data = response.data;
             if(data!='') {  
               for(var i=0;i<837;i++) {
                 document.getElementById(i).src=data[i].charac;  
               }
               console.log(data);
             }
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            alert(error);
        })
}
```

If u want to see the demo go here https://ligalavanda.com/registration.php

Comment: Your loop is very tight, you need to give the interface time to update

Comment: I would say it's an issue with loading 837 images at once and not with code.
On live page there are multiple tabs, maybe you should load only images of current tab?

Comment: *"If u want to see the demo go here"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally [using Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). More: [here](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: I agree it's crazy to load so many images at once and expect it to be fast. You're generating a huge number of HTTP requests. Just load the ones you need. Consider changing the UI so it shows a smaller number at once, and have a "more..." button similar - or create more tabs or something. Also, consider, if you haven't already, using some caching

Comment: i used 837 here because total i have 836 elements and i m retrieving 836 data in JSON response

Comment: that doesn't mean you have load them **all at once**. Also hard-coding the number into your JavaScript is silly...what if you add more characters? You don't want to have to release a new version of your front-end just for that. Just use the `length` property of the array, e.g. `for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {`. Then you don't know the number of characters in advance, instead the code will just loop until it runs out of items.

Comment: @ADyson i know u r right but actually i have 836 elements in my db which will neither increase nor decrease it is fixed thats why i use hard code further i have 837 elements in html in and  element's id starts from 0 and and ends at 836 and i use id to change src

Comment: "it is fixed"...for now. You can't anticipate future requirements (even if you think you can. Everything changes eventually). It's good practice to use `length` instead of hard-coding, then you don't ever have to worry or remember about it. Even if the value really is fixed forever it won't hurt to use length, the code will still work. The change is trivial and it will take you less time to make the change than to argue about it :-)

Comment: Anyway that's really not the main point here. You have a performance problem because you're trying to load too many images at once. It's crazy because the user isn't even able to see most of them. Just load the ones which will actually be visible to begin with. If the user changes to view another tab, then load the images for that tab at that time. This will make the initial loading faster, and won't waste time and resources loading things which might never be viewed. This is a common pattern in websites which have a lot of content on their pages. And also, do some caching.

Answer (score 0):

You have a performance problem because you're trying to load too many images at once. 837 is really a large number - it generates 837 separate HTTP requests, for one thing. It's even more crazy because the user isn't even able to see most of them when they are first loaded (they are hidden in separate tabs).

My advice would be: just load the ones which will actually be visible to begin with. If the user changes to view another tab, then load the images for that tab at that time. This will make the initial loading faster, and won't waste time and resources loading things which might never be viewed.

(There are other ways you could potentially optimise this further as well, by using caching and/or CDNs, which you can research separately).